# Formatting SQL Query into a proper JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

Attempting to convert the following query to use JOINs without success:

```
select * from usrdata
   where recordid=any(select usrdataid from usrclix
      where clidataid=any(select recordid from clidata
         where subdataid='dd87cb0c-e571-11e6-b2b8-d4ae52cc00a8'));
```

I've tried LEFT JOINS, JOINS, etc but I am unable to get the correct result set back.  Can someone please help me properly foramt this statements using JOINS.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any error to report ? Or give an input and your expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```
SELECT * 
FROM userdata u
LEFT JOIN usrclix uc ON u.recordid = uc.userdataid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT recordid FROM clidata WHERE subdataid = 'dd87cb0c-e571-11e6-b2b8-d4ae52cc00a8') as cd ON c.clidataid = cd.recordid;
```